# Unable to click on the cruise room number (svg element xpath)

Tags: svg, xpath

I am facing problem in locating a room number using xpath. The room numbers belong to a cruise party.

Here is the svg image link for which I have located the xpath for the room number assigned.

https://secure.stg1.espresso.cruisingpower.com/cruisingpower/content/shared_assets/svg/svg_r_AN_1734/IDP-DECK08.svg

I want to click on one of the rooms.

I have used below xpath:

```
//svg:path[@id='R8320' and @style='fill: #D3B6D7;stroke:#999999; cursor: pointer;']
```

It is locating the xpath in Firefox but when I run it it doesn't click.

I have used many combinations of svg xpaths. None of them are working.

Answer (score 0):

try `//*[@id='R8320']` or `//*[local-name()='path' and @id='R8320']` or `//*[local-name()='svg']//*[local-name()='path' and @id='R8320']`

should these elements be clickable?

Comment: None of the xpaths worked. Yes, these room numbers are clickable.

Comment: No they're not...well not on the page you gave anyway.

Comment: I can't share you the website because of some security issues. May be we can connect with skype id's and we can discuss.. It will click on the room# if we go through website.. That was a part of svg image that i have shared with you.

Comment: maybe the elements are in an iframe? you'd have to switch to the iframe first.